# Tabela HTML dentro de outra tabela em um foreach no PHP

Tags: php, html, foreach

Gostaria de saber se é possível Adicionar uma `Table` `HTML` dentro de outra tabela em um `foreach`.

Explicação pra eu necessitar disso:
Eu tenho os orçamentos no banco de dados e cada orçamento pode ter muitos itens de composição.
Gostaria de listar os itens de composição de baixo dos seus respectivos orçamentos.

Estou tentando mas o layout está quebrando.

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Descricao</th>
      <th>Quantidade</th>
      <th>Valor unidade</th>
      <th>Valor total</th>
      <th>Cliente</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $itemCount = 1 ?>
    <?php foreach ($orcamentos->findAll() as $orcamento) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td>Item <?= $itemCount ?></td>
        <td><?= $orcamento['descricao'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $orcamento['quantidade'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $orcamento['valor_unidade'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $orcamento['valor_total'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $clientes->where('id', $orcamento['cliente_id'])->first()['nome_cliente'] ?></td>

        <td>
          <table border="2">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Descricao</th>
                <th>Quantidade</th>
                <th>Valor unidade</th>
                <th>Valor total</th>
                <th>Fornecedor</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>A</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php $itemCount += 1 ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sim é possível, mas do jeito que está no seu código, aninhar uma `<table>` dentro do `<tbody>` não, pode ser aninhada dentro de um `<td>`. Crie uma `<td>` e insira a table lá, use colspan se for preciso

Comment: Ficou uma do lado da outra....@RicardoPontual

Comment: pode colocar o código na pergunta? ai da pra entender melhor

Comment: @RicardoPontual, Editei a pergunta com o código atualizado...

Comment: ai vai ficar ao lado mesmo, ficaria melhor fazer numa linha abaixo, veja esse exemplo que montei, se quiser coloco numa resposta: https://jsfiddle.net/4hrcz01w/1/

Comment: @RicardoPontual, funcionou, coloca como resposta pra eu marcar aushuash <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O elemento `<table>` pode ser inserido em outra tabela, dentro de um elemento `<td>`, assim poderia fazer algo assim:

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Descricao</th>
      <th>Quantidade</th>
      <th>Valor unidade</th>
      <th>Valor total</th>
      <th>Cliente</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>descricao</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>Fulano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outra tabela</td>
        <td colspan="5" style="background-color: yellow">
          <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Descricao</th>
            <th>Quantidade</th>
            <th>Valor unidade</th>
            <th>Valor total</th>
            <th>Fornecedor</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>descricao</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Fulano</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note que, como a segunda tabela é inserida na estrutura da primeira, usei o `colspan` para fazer o merge das células e manter o alinhamento e estrutura

Comment: É possível criar uma ul dentro de uma table também? por incrível que pareça, surgiu a necessidade e acontece a mesma coisa, ela quebra

Comment: sim, dentro da `<td>` pode :)